# Css Selector, Select only the father of a particular child

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
 <h1>
        <span class="teste">
            Conteúdo Teste
        </span>
    </h1>
```

I can not modify the HTML . Must enter css attributes only in h1 that has the span with the class test within . How do I ?

Comment: which attributes? what's the purpose?

Comment: I'm afraid, there is no way of doing that. take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Some concepts but it isn't possible. https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: is it javascript allowed?

Comment: `has` selector is coming (don't know when fully supported) to the rescue in CSS 4. Then you will be able to do things like `h1:has(span.test) { ... }`

Comment: what do you want to style? if it's something under `.teste` or besides `.teste`, there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to select parent in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

My bad i got it wrong.Look into this..

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: That's not targeting the `<h1>`, it's targeting the `<span class="teste">` inside the `<h1>`